# Has anyone came across this problem? [vue/no-multiple-template-root] The template root disallows 'v-for' directives.eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

It is actually a three problems in one:

[vue/no-multiple-template-root]
The template root disallows 'v-for' directives.eslint-plugin-vue

[vue/no-parsing-error]
Parsing error: Expected to be an alias, but got empty.eslint-plugin-vue

[vue/valid-v-for]
Expected 'v-bind:key' directive to use the variables which are defined by the 'v-for' directive.eslint-plugin-vue

Can anyone help me please I am so fed with searching online for it everywhere

```
enter code
```

```js
<template>
  <div class="post" v-for="post" in posts >
    <div><strong>Title</strong>{{post.title}}</div>
    <div><strong>Desctiption</strong>{{post.body}}</div>
  </div>

</template>


<script>

export default{

  data(){
    return{
      posts:[
        { id: 1, title: 'javascript', body: "the desctiption"},
        { id: 2, title: 'javascript2', body: "the desctiption"},
        { id: 3, title: 'javascript3', body: "the desctiption"},
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue.js must have a single element at the root of the template. If you have a`v-for` directive, when the DOM is populated there will be multiple `<div>` elements at the root, which Vue does not allow.

So you just need to add another `<div>` element to surround your `v-for` div.

Then, move the `in posts` within your quotes and add a `:key`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="post" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
      <div><strong>Title</strong>{{post.title}}</div>
      <div><strong>Desctiption</strong>{{post.body}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In vue two you should one root element, using v-for loop will render multiple elements in the template like :

```
 <div class="post" >
  ...
 </div>
  <div class="post" >
  ...
 </div>
```

to avoid this add an extra div and bind key to the post id `:key="post.id"`:

```
<template>
<div class="posts">
  <div class="post" v-for="post in posts"  :key="post.id">
    <div><strong>Title</strong>{{post.title}}</div>
    <div><strong>Desctiption</strong>{{post.body}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```